# Why are these popular SMTP providers suggesting I use a subdomain?

Tags: smtp, spoofing

When adding a new mail domain to my Mailgun account, I noticed a message informing me I should use a subdomain instead. Intrigued by this I clicked on the [FAQ link they provided](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#how-do-i-pick-a-domain-name-for-my-mailgun-account), but unfortunately it contained little to no technical information as to why.

After some back and forth with a colleague about this we concluded that it can only hurt the reputation of Mailgun as they are "spoofing mail" from the top level domain. When we tried to add the same domain to another SMTP provider we saw the same message appear, and again, no technical information in their FAQ.

I googled around to look for evidence as to why they might do this but came back empty handed.

This seems so backwards to me. Why would they recommend adding them as a subdomain rather than the top level?

(I want them to use the From: xxx@topleveldomain.com, not From: xxx@sub.topleveldomain.com)

Comment: I can't see where they are telling you to use a subdomain? The opposite, actually: _If your company’s primary domain is mycompany.com, we recommend the following domain names for mailgun:

mycompany.com, unless you’re already using this name for your corporate email;_ the second and third recommendations are subdomains or a different domain.

Comment: It was in a warning message when attepting to add the top level domain, suggesting me to use "mg.domain.com" or "m.domain.com".

Comment: Most people will already use a subdomain, because they are using their domain for corporate email.

Comment: From the docs, "some companies will use a different domains or subdomains for bulk marketing mailings and transactional or corporate mail in order to keep the reputations separate." <- basically, they are a bulk mailing service, so, that means if you don't use a sub domain it is likely that all of your regular email will start getting blocked.